# How to programmatically set the featured image of the product based on the image of the product category to which it belongs

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have many products but the pictures will actually be category pictures. I want the product featured images to be automatically the category image they are in.

There is a problem with the code below.

```
function default_category_featured_image() {
global $post;
$featured_image_exists = has_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
              
if (!$featured_image_exists)  {
$attached_image = get_children( "post_parent=$post->ID&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&numberposts=1" );

if ($attached_image) {
                          
foreach ($attached_image as $attachment_id => $attachment) {
set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $attachment);
}}
else if ( in_category('61') ) {
    set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, '4436'); //arçelik
}
else if ( in_category('64') ) {
    set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, '4435'); //beko
}
else if ( in_category('59') ) {
    set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, '4434'); //LG
}
else if ( in_category('60') ) {
    set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, '4458'); //Philips
    }
else if ( in_category('66') ) {
    set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, '4160'); //Profilo
        }
else if ( in_category('58') ) {
    set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, '4159'); //samsung
            }
else if ( in_category('65') ) {
    set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, '4160'); //seg
                        }
else if ( in_category('62') ) {
    set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, '4433'); //sony
                                    }
else if ( in_category('63') ) {
    set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, '4160'); //vestel
                                                }
else {
set_post_thumbnail($post->ID, '4435'); //genel
wp_reset_postdata();
                               }
                               
                           }
                        
      }
add_action('the_post', 'default_category_featured_image');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set product thumbnails using the **[init](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/)** hook.

> Make sure you **remove** the `programmatically_set_thumbnail_to_product` function **from the functions.php file once it's done**.

**DATA TO BE REPLACED**:

- Enter the **product category id** "Genel" in place of the `genel` key of the `$thumbnail_ids` array.

*Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

```
// updates the thumbnails of all products based on the product category image
add_action( 'init', 'programmatically_set_thumbnail_to_product' );
function programmatically_set_thumbnail_to_product() {

    // returns the ids of all products
    $ids = wc_get_products(
        array(
            'return' => 'ids',
            'limit' => -1
        )
    );

    // set the ids of the product categories
    $thumbnail_ids = array(
        58      => 4159, // Samsung
        59      => 4434, // LG
        60      => 4458, // Philips
        61      => 4436, // Arçelik
        62      => 4433, // Sony
        63      => 4160, // Vestel
        64      => 4435, // Beko
        65      => 4160, // Seg
        66      => 4160, // Profilo
        'genel' => 4435  // Genel (set the id of the product category "Genel" as a key)
    );

    // for each product
    foreach ( $ids as $product_id ) {
        // for each product category
        foreach ( $thumbnail_ids as $cat_id => $thumbnail_id ) {
            // check if the product belongs to a product category
            if ( has_term( $cat_id, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
                // if yes, set the product thumbnail
                set_post_thumbnail( $product_id, $thumbnail_id);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This function will set the thumbnails of all products based on the thumbnail of the respective product category.

Once added to `functions.php` refresh the product catalog page in the frontend (for example) and you will notice that all images will be changed/set.

> **Then remove it from functions.php and add this other function.**

The function below will be performed every time a product is saved or updated *(to automatically set the image of new products)*.

**DATA TO BE REPLACED**:

- Enter the **product category id** "Genel" in place of the `genel` key of the `$thumbnail_ids` array.

*Always add it to functions.php.*

```
// when a product is saved or updated it sets the image based on the product category
add_action( 'save_post', 'programmatically_set_thumbnail_to_new_product' );
function programmatically_set_thumbnail_to_new_product( $product_id ) {

    // set the ids of the product categories
    $thumbnail_ids = array(
        58      => 4159, // Samsung
        59      => 4434, // LG
        60      => 4458, // Philips
        61      => 4436, // Arçelik
        62      => 4433, // Sony
        63      => 4160, // Vestel
        64      => 4435, // Beko
        65      => 4160, // Seg
        66      => 4160, // Profilo
        'genel' => 4435  // Genel (set the id of the product category "Genel" as a key)
    );
    
    // for each product category
    foreach ( $thumbnail_ids as $cat_id => $thumbnail_id ) {
        // check if the product belongs to a product category
        if ( has_term( $cat_id, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            // retrieve product thumbnail id
            $current_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $product_id );
            // if it is different from that of the product category
            if ( $current_thumbnail_id == false || $current_thumbnail_id != $thumbnail_id ) {
                // set the product thumbnail
                set_post_thumbnail( $product_id, $thumbnail_id );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Both codes have been tested and work.*

Comment: Thanks for answer, i was about to go crazy... Thank you so much again.